# Only the first media Query works

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, responsive

i am working on a grid-based website and U wanted to create a mobile version. However, when coding, only the first media query works. It does not matter how ridiculous the code is I write in the second jQuery, nothing changes. 
Can anybody help me?

```
@media (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 401px) {
    .container {

    display: grid;

    margin-left:3.5%;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, minmax(75px,1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(50px,1fr));


    grid-template-areas: 
        "a a a a a a b b b "
        "c c c d d d e e e "
        "f f f g g g h h h "
        "i i i j j j k k k ";
}
}   
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .container {

    display: grid;

    margin-left:3.5%;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr));


    grid-template-areas: 
        "a a a a a a "
        "b b b c c c "
        "d d d e e e "
        "f f f g g g "
        "h h h i i i "
        "j j j k k k ";
}
```

Comment: and what about the HTML code ? and why the jQurey tag?

Comment: A suggestion: When you start developing a web application, you should apply a mobile first implementation. E.g. all your css rules would, by default, customize the mobile representation of the website. The media queries would gradually customize the page design for the bigger screens, going from an approach like this: `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {/* Rules for tablets */}`, followed by `@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {/* Rules for desktops */}`, followed by `@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {/* Rules for large desktops */}`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `@media (max-width: 400px)`, write `@media screen and (max-width: 400px)`
You forgot to close the media queries after the .container at the end by the way.